# Indentation problem in lists using easylist

Tags: xetex, page-breaking, indentation, easylist

I am making a summary of Hindi grammar in Latex, and am having a small issue with enumerating items using the package `easylist`.

The indentation is fine when the whole list is on one page, but i get larger indentation than wanted when the list is on 2 pages (page break).

Is there a solution to this? My script is pasted below.

EDIT: i am compiling this using Xelatex

[I googled for a while for an answer, but can't seem to find one, sorry if this is too nooby]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Command \InputIfFileExists}

%%% For accessing system, OTF and TTF fonts
%%% (would have been loaded by polylossia anyway)
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%% For language switching -- like babel, but for xelatex
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{hindi} %% or other languages


% Main serif font for English (Latin alphabet) text
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}

% define fonts for other languages
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}

% Set up the font commands:
\newcommand{\noto}[1]{{{\selectlanguage{hindi}\devanagarifont #1}}}

% List packages
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Aussprache}

\begin{german}
\section{Aussprache des inhärenten \textit{a} (HB1 p.5-7)}\\\\
\noto अ vor \noto ह = wie “e” in Bett: Bsp.: \noto{अहमद, पहले}\\\\  
Folgt dem Hochlaut ein anderer Vokal, tritt diese Regel nicht ein. 
Bsp.: \noto {रहा}\\
\\
\\
%\clearpage
\noindent Das dem Konsonanten inhärente \noto अ wird nicht ausgesprochen/transkribiert:\\

\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
& \underline{Im Wortauslaut:}\\
&& Im Wortauslaut. Bsp.: \noto{काम} kām\\

&& Auslautende \noto अ wird stark verkürzt ausgesprochen bei:\\

&&& \noto{य, र, ल, व} am Wortende.\\
Bsp.: \noto{योग्य} yogy^{a}.\\

&&& \noto{इय, ईय} am Wortende.\\
Bsp: \noto{प्रिय} priy^{a}\\

& \underline{Im 2. akṣar (Silbenzeichen):}\\
&& Aus 3 akṣar bestehenden Wörter, die auf einen Langvokal enden.\\
Bsp.: \noto{आदमी} ādmī (nicht ādamī).\\
Wegen diese Ausspracheregel können einige Fremdwörter, die eine Konsonantengruppen enthalten, mit oder ohne Ligatur geschrieben werden. Bsp.: \noto{कुर्सी/कुरसी}.\\

&& Aus 4 akṣar bestehenden Wörter. Bsp.: \noto{अदरक} adkrak (nicht adarak)

\end{easylist}
\end{german}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I was in Documentclass {Book} and had not specified onesided, so i believe Latex was aligning odd pages to the left and even pages to the right (or vice-versa), which is why elements in the list did not look aligned when split over two consecutive pages.

Silly nooby mistake ...